# Regex url link html to other content

Tags: php, regex

Example:

```
Access – <a href="http://extratorrent.cc/search/?search=Cotent">Torrent Search</a> – <a href="http://link1.com/Text">Link 1</a> – <a href="http://link2.com/Text">Link 2</a> – <a href="http://link3.com/Text">Link 3</a> – <a href="http://link4.com/Text">Link 4</a>
```

I want use regex to make it like this

```
Access – <a href="http://extratorrent.cc/search/?search=Cotent">Torrent Search</a> – AAABBBCCC
```

I just know `</?a(|\s+[^>]+)>`to remove url link but don't know how to regex like content above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
<?php
$input = 'Access – <a href="http://extratorrent.cc/search/?search=Cotent">Torrent Search</a> – <a href="http://link1.com/Text">Link 1</a> – <a href="http://link2.com/Text">Link 2</a> – <a href="http://link3.com/Text">Link 3</a> – <a href="http://link4.com/Text">Link 4</a>';

$output = preg_replace("/<a href=\"http:\/\/(?!extratorrent.cc)[^\"]+\">([^<]+)<\/a>/", '$1', $input);
// remove all links
$output = preg_replace("/\ –? Link [0-9]+/", '', $output);
// CONCAT TEXT
$output.= " AABBCCDD";

echo $output;

/*
output:
Access – <a href="http://extratorrent.cc/search/?search=Cotent">Torrent Search</a> AABBCCDD
*/
```

Comment: You're best. But "// remove all links expect first" wrong my mean, I want to remove all after "...Torrent Search</a>" and add some words after it like "...Torrent Search</a> - AAABBBCCC"

Comment: @user7819129 I have edited the answer, If it is OK, please check the "V" and put upvote, thank you

Comment: Thank you so much !